# Don't use capturing groups in c# Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

I am writing a regular expression in Visual Studio 2013 using C#

I have the following scenario:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("%%Text%%More text%%More more text", "(?<!^)%%[^%]+%%");
```

But my problem is that I don't want to capture groups. The reason is that with capture groups `match.Value` contains `%%More text%%` and my idea is the get on `match.Value` directly the string: `More text`

The string to get will be always between the second and the third group of %%
Another approach is that the string will be always between the fourth and fifth %

I tried:

```
Regex.Match("%%Text%%More text%%More more text", "(?:(?<!^)%%[^%]+%%)");
```

But with no luck.

I want to use match.Value because all my regex are in a database table.

Is there a way to "transform" that regex to one not using capturing groups and the in `match.value` the desired string?

Comment: here is a good place to start.. have you read any of the examples or consulted the documentation on [Regex.Match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure you have no `%`s inside double `%%`s, you can just use lookarounds like this:

```
(?<=^%%[^%]*%%)[^%]+(?=%%)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^
```

If you have single-% delimited strings (like `%text1%text2%text3%text4%text5%text6`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%25%5B%5E%25%5D*%25)%5B%5E%25%5D%2B(%3F%3D%25)&i=%25text1%25text2%25text3%25text4%25text5%25text6)):

```
(?<=^%[^%]*%)[^%]+(?=%)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%25%25%5b%5e%25%5d*%25%25)%5b%5e%25%5d%2b(%3f%3d%25%25)&i=%25%25Text%25%25More+text%25%25More+more+text)

And in case it is between the 4th and the 5th:

```
(?<=^%%(?:[^%]*%%){3})[^%]+(?=%%)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
```

For single-% delimited strings (see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%25(%3F%3A%5B%5E%25%5D*%25)%7B3%7D)%5B%5E%25%5D%2B(%3F%3D%25)&i=%25text1%25text2%25text3%25text4%25text5%25text6)):

```
(?<=^%(?:[^%]*%){3})[^%]+(?=%)
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%25%25(%3F%3A%5B%5E%25%5D*%25%25)%7B3%7D)%5B%5E%25%5D%2B(%3F%3D%25%25)&i=%25%25Text1%25%25Text2%25%25Text3%25%25More%20text%25%25More%20more%20text)

Both the regexps contain a variable-width lookbehind and the same lookahead to restrict the context the *1 or more characters other than `%`* appears in.

The `(?<=^%%[^%]*%%)` makes sure the is `%%[something_other_then_%]%%` right after the beginning of the string, and `(?<=^%%(?:[^%]*%%){3})` matches `%%[substring_not_having_%]%%[substring_not_having_%]%%[substring_not_having_%]%%` after the string start.

**In case there can be single `%` symbols inside the double `%%`**, you can use an unroll-the-loop regex (see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%25%25(%3F%3A%5B%5E%25%5D*(%3F%3A%25(%3F!%25)%5B%5E%25%5D*)*%25%25)%7B3%7D)%5B%5E%25%5D*(%3F%3A%25(%3F!%25)%5B%5E%25%5D*)*(%3F%3D%25%25)&i=%25%25Text1%25%25Text2%25%25Text3%25%25More%20%26%20text%25%25More%20more%20text)):

```
(?<=^%%(?:[^%]*(?:%(?!%)[^%]*)*%%){3})[^%]*(?:%(?!%)[^%]*)*(?=%%)
```

Which is matching the same stuff that can be matched with [`(?<=^%%(?:.*?%%){3}).*?(?=%%)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%25%25(%3f%3a.*%3f%25%25)%7b3%7d).*%3f(%3f%3d%25%25)&i=%25%25Text1%25%25Text2%25%25Text3%25%25More+%26+text%25%25More+more+text). For short strings, the `.*?` based solution should work faster. For very long input texts, use the unrolled version.

Comment: yes I'm sure is not going to happend that. I tested it and worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Good, I will still post a solution that accounts for cases when there can be a single `%` inside the double `%%`.

Comment: The second solution: (?<=^%%(?:[^%]*%%){3})[^%]+(?=%%) didn't worked but worked if i change it for: (?<=^%(?:[^%]*%){3})[^%]+(?=%) maeby is a typo.

Comment: Well, I see you have double `%%` in the original question, so I used two `%` in the pattern. If you have one, there is really no problem then with using `[^%]+`.

Comment: Sorry seems that i didn't explained well in my previous comment. The approach of using 4th and 5th place doesn't match anything in the string: %%Text%%More text%%More more text   but if i use (?<=^%(?:[^%]*%){3})[^%]+(?=%)  yes because to be the the between the 4th and 5th need to use single % so will work for example with strings like: %text1%text2%text3%text4%text5%text6 That will get text4

Comment: I have updated the answer to include regexps that work with single-`%` delimited strings.